# Lazy image loader

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking for a jQuery lazy image loader (prevents images from being loaded until they are visible on the page), but can only find one and it appears to not work anymore. All links I have found drive traffic to this page:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Which is from 2007 and states it is not being supported anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out JAIL: http://www.sebastianoarmelibattana.com/projects/jail